# How to get locale DisplayName which is not defined in java

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, internationalization, locale

So I have to display a Burmese(Zawgyi) in my language selector dropdown,however there is no locale supported in Java for Burmese(Zawgyi).We have a locale "my" for Burmese , but that is different than Burmese(Zawgyi).

```
<select id="local" name="Locale" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${site.locales}">
            <option value="${item eq 'in'? 'id': item}" ${locale eq (item eq 'in'? 'id': item)?"selected":""}>${item.displayLanguage}</option>
        </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I am using "zg" for my locale , which is not supported in java.So how can I proceed.

Comment: "zg" is not supported in Java because it is not standard. The closest you can come to a standard for Burmese - Zawgyi is my-Qaag (see http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#unicode_script_subtag_validity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have used and it seems to work

```
<select id="local" name="Locale" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${site.locales}">
            <option value="${item eq 'in'? 'id': item}" ${locale eq (item eq 'in'? 'id': item)?"selected":""}>${item eq 'zg' ? 'Burmese(Zawgyi)' : item.displayLanguage}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```